# Chrome crashes when I turn on/off fullscreen on Youtube and locks down the screen

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

When I'm watching Youtube videos, Chrome oftenly crashes when I switch to fullscreen or exit it. But it doesn't pop up any window or notice or anything. Mouse keeps moving but everything else is completely unresponsive. Voice of the video is still heard in background. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and after logging in, I try `killall chrome` however it does no good and I'm forced to restart the computer, causing data loss.

Any ideas about the source of the problem or any suggestions?

Also, are there any commands of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (I forgot the name) that restarts the launcher? That might work.

Comment: I have the same issue. Even though it's only a little better than restarting - restarting the x server by executing `sudo service lightdm restart` works too for making the computer responsive again.

Answer (score 1):

I have opened a ticket on Chrome's issue tracker about this issue, but nothing has come out of it until now...

Turning off hardware acceleration does fix it, and so does using GNOME Shell instead of Unity in my case.

But both aren't fixes, just workarounds...

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was happening only with Youtube but today it also happened on Facebook.

Comment: Yep, happens on every video in fullscreen mode. Even a normal page in fullscreen (F11) makes it happen sometimes for me. But no work seems to be done towards fixing it. Opened the issue when Chrome 47 was in Beta and it's still there in Chrome 50 unstable. Linux users really are second class citizens according to Google.

Comment: Well Google is making a ton of money from Linux. They should be more interested in the topic in my opinion.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and have not found a solution, it even happens in midori or firefox, except it doesn't hang the system, just the browser.
Is it at problem in Unity, Xubuntu seems to work fine?